# MakeFile контроль прослеживания заголовков

Tags: makefile

В процессе написания проги добавляются заголовки и иногда забывается добавить прослеживание перекомпиляции файла, если заголовок изменился. Я написал двойной контроль над забывчивостью :

header1.h :

```
# ifndef CONTROLheader1h
# error not CONTROLheader1h
# endif
...
```

header2.h :

```
# ifndef CONTROLheader2h
# error not CONTROLheader2h
# endif
...
```

source.c :

```
# define CONTROLheader1h
# define CONTROLheader2h
...
# include <header1.h>
# include <header2.h>
```

Дальше вручную прослеживаю в `Makefile` забыл-ли дописать зависимость :

Makefile :

```
source.o : source.c header1.h header2.h
...
```

Вопрос : какие есть удобные варианты написания `Makefile`, чтобы не забывать про зависимости.

Comment: чего именно вы хотите добиться от программы *make*?

Comment: К `make` претензий не имею, просто не знаю как народ контролирует большие программы (по количеству файлов и хедеров). @aleksandr barakin

Comment: задам вопрос по-другому. а что, по-вашему, произойдёт, если вы уберёте `header1.h header2.h` из пререквизитов цели `source.o`?

Comment: Убираем `header1.h` из `Makefile`. При изменении хедера `header1.h` и переделывании функции из этого хедера компилятор не станет перекомпилировать `source.o`. Прога будет очень **плохо** работать. @aleksandr barakin

Comment: Возможно я сейчас удивлю, но вы не пробовали вообще отказаться от make и производить полную сборку каждый раз?

Comment: От хорошей привычки тяжело отказываться. Он компилирует в восемь раз быстрее. (8 ядер проца) И выборочно. Слушаю ваше предложение. @user7860670

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319579/what-are-the-drawbacks-of-single-source-project-structures/46321758#46321758

Comment: ну, если азы понимаете, то тогда вам сюда: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html#Automatic-Prerequisites

Comment: Тяжело пока переводить быстро, но кажется компилировать в один `.o` у меня не получиться. Половина `g++ ..cpp` и вторая `gcc ..c`. @user7860670

Comment: Ну тогда потренируюсь с флагом `-M`. Может быть получиться. @aleksandr barakin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобная проблема возникает не раз и эта задача давно уже решена. Попробуйте в консоли запустить такое

```
сс -M source.c
```

и увидите необходимый список

```
source.o : source.c header1.h header2.h
```

прям то, что нужно.

В принципе этого уже достаточно, что бы запустить что то вида

```
find . -name *.c -exec cc -M {}\; > MakeFile.mk
```

и подцепить этот файл к своему Makefile через include. Но и это можно автоматизировать. И это описано в официальной документации https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html

Потом можно посмотреть на пример здесь http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/ и сделать себе хорошо.

```
DEPDIR := .deps
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.d

COMPILE.c = $(CC) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c

%.o : %.c
%.o : %.c $(DEPDIR)/%.d | $(DEPDIR)
        $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

$(DEPDIR): ; @mkdir -p $@

DEPFILES := $(SRCS:%.c=$(DEPDIR)/%.d)
$(DEPFILES):

include $(wildcard $(DEPFILES))
```

Comment: Интересно. Вряд-ли мне нужен флаг `-M`. Я не так часто переустанавливаю компилятор. Скорее всего хватит `-MM`. Не знаю как всё это собрать из нескольких частей. Половина `.cpp` другая `.c`. Может наверное сделать два мейкфала.

Comment: "я не так часто переустанавливаю компилятор" ??? Это не имеет никакого отношения к установке компилятора. И нужно будет вместо одного набора целей для c файлов, сделать ещё их копию для cpp. Делов то.

Comment: флаг `-M` следит за всеми заголовками C/C++ библиотеки. А `-MM` нет. Как собирать `%.o : %.c` и `%.o : %.cpp` ? Команды и флаги то компиляции разные.

Answer (score 0):

Со всеми советами разобрался. Убрал ручные зависимости хедеров. Оставил только по-файловые команды. Чтобы можно было менять опции и языки (C или C++). Любая перекомпиляция файла обновляет зависимости с помощью опции `-MM` (*которая не реагирует на изменение библиотеки*).

Makefile :

```
OBJECTS = o/a.o o/b.o o/c.o o/d.o

CGCC = gcc -MM $(1).c -MT o/$(1).o > o/$(1).d && \
 gcc -c -Os $(1).c -o o/$(1).o

CGPP = g++ -MM $(1).cpp -MT o/$(1).o > o/$(1).d && \
 g++ -c -Os $(1).cpp -o o/$(1).o

build: $(OBJECTS)
    g++ $(OBJECTS) -o a

o/a.o:
    $(call CGCC,a)

o/b.o:
    $(call CGCC,b)

o/c.o:
    $(call CGPP,c)

o/d.o:
    $(call CGPP,d)

clean:
    rm -f o/*.d o/*.o

-include o/*.d
```